# How to monitor GPS updates ONLY when Android device is moving

Tags: android, gps, location, location-services

Once device has started to move, I want to start gps updates:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

and as soon as device has stopped, I want to stop gps updates.

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

How can I do it? What best approach?

Comment: I am stuck in the same problem

Comment: If it stops updating when the device is not moving, how can it tell when it started to move again? Probably best bet is loop every n minutes and check if the device has moved.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to NOT do! I can't keep "pooling" gps every minute. Even so, if I get gps coordinates now and compare with last one and see I'm not moving, and start to move now, I'll miss 1 minute of movment, and this is what I'm trying to solve!

Comment: Then monitor GPS continuously.

Comment: Then battery will drain very fast!

Comment: If you need to track movement down to better-than-minute resolution, you don't really have a choice, other than relying on the user to toggle it appropriately.

Comment: @Christian what is the solution you have used?

Comment: @dpsingh Any solution you recommend?

Comment: I have little fluppy lib that solves my problem.

Comment: No solution yet... sorry.

Comment: What about using the sensors to detect significant motion. I haven't done it but seems promising. https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#significant_motion

Comment: Too much battery consumption... seems promising, but they have a lot work to get better than is.

Answer (score 0):

While creating [LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) object add [setSmallestDisplacement(10)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) where **10** meters is the minimum displacement that the device must travel to get location update.